# Win32 Exception: 0xc0000005 | dll injection

Tags: c#, dll-injection

So today I tried dll injection to game (assult cube) to test my experience with my job.
But I got problems with Win32 Exception: 0xc0000005.

My code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Memory;


namespace AssultCube_Cheat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Mem assultcube = new Mem();


        public static string RifleAmmo = "ac_client.exe+0x0017E0A8";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int PID = assultcube.GetProcIdFromName("ac_client");
            if (PID > 0)
            {
                assultcube.OpenProcess(PID);
                Thread WA = new Thread(writeAmmo) { IsBackground = true };
                WA.Start();
            }
        }

        private void writeAmmo()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    assultcube.WriteMemory(RifleAmmo, "int", "80");
                    Thread.Sleep(2);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(2);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I tried updating my computer drivers, upgrading my system to Windows 11 but problem didnt fix.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow tutoras, please do have a [tour] and learn [ask] including how to write [mcve]. also `0xc0000005` stands for memory access violation..

Comment: You either got a wrong address or the page it is in isn't made writable. I don't know what Memory.Mem is, it may also be a problem specific to this library. Not much more can be said here.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).